# TypeError: Cannot read property 'paramMap' of undefined while running my angular test

Tags: angular, angular-test, angular-testing-library

I am getting an error when running my angular 2 tests. the following is the error i receive.

```
CreateFlightComponent should send a request to create a flight
TypeError: Cannot read property 'paramMap' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'paramMap' of undefined
```

the following is test class .

```
describe('CreateFlightComponent', () => {
  let component: CreateFlightComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CreateFlightComponent>;
  let router: Router;

  let getCampaignSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let createFlightSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let navigateSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let toastSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let getUserSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let getApprovalPeriodDateSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let getTagOnsSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let myActivatedRouteObserver;
  
  beforeEach(() => {

    const  myActivatedRouteObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
      myActivatedRouteObserver = observer;
     });

  });

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CreateFlightComponent],
      providers: [
        FlightsService,
        CampaignsService,
        ToastService,
        AuthenticationService,
        SettingsService,
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: myActivatedRouteObserver
        },
        { provide: ConfigService, useClass: ConfigServiceMock }
      ],
      imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();

  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    const campaignsService = TestBed.get(CampaignsService);
    getCampaignSpy = spyOn(campaignsService, 'get').and.returnValue(
      of({
        id: '123'
      })
    );

    const flightsService = TestBed.get(FlightsService);
    createFlightSpy = spyOn(flightsService, 'create').and.returnValue(
      of({ id: 'f321' })
    );
    getTagOnsSpy = spyOn(flightsService, 'getTagOns').and.returnValue(of([]));
    spyOn(flightsService, 'getTagOnTargetRecipients').and.returnValue(
      of([] as TagOnTargetRecipient[])
    );

    const toastService = TestBed.get(ToastService);
    toastSpy = spyOn(toastService, 'toast');

    const authenticationService = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);
    getUserSpy = spyOn(authenticationService, 'getUser').and.returnValue(
      of({
        account: { features: [{ code: FeatureCode.PROFILES }] } as Account
      } as User)
    );

    const settingsService = TestBed.get(SettingsService);
    getApprovalPeriodDateSpy = spyOn(
      settingsService,
      'getApprovalPeriodDate'
    ).and.returnValue(of(moment(new Date()).add(7, 'days')));

    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateFlightComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });



    it('should send a request to create a flight',  () => {
      

      fixture.detectChanges();

      myActivatedRouteObserver.next(convertToParamMap({ id: '123' }));

      component.handleSave({ currentValue: { name: 'test' }, stepIndex: 1 });
  
      expect(createFlightSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        jasmine.objectContaining({
          name: 'test',
          campaign: { id: '123' }
        })
      );
    });
});
```

The following is my angular component class.

```
export class CreateFlightComponent implements OnInit {
  campaign: Campaign;
  isLoading = true;
  isSaving = false;
  hasProfileFeature = false;
  hasLocationFeature = false;
  hasRecipientGatheringFeature = false;
  hasParameterisedContactListFeature = false;
  hasInteractiveSMSFeature = false;
  account: Account;
  inventories: Inventory[] = [];
  tagOns: TagOn[] = [];
  tagOnTargetRecipients: TagOnTargetRecipient[] = [];
  approvalPeriodStartDate: Moment;
  parameterisedContactList: ParameterisedContactList;
  addressProfile: AddressProfile;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private flightsService: FlightsService,
    private campaignsService: CampaignsService,
    private toastService: ToastService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private settingsService: SettingsService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        tap(() => (this.isLoading = true)),
        switchMap(paramMap =>
          combineLatest(
            this.authenticationService.getUser(),
            this.campaignsService.get(paramMap.get('id')),
            this.settingsService.getApprovalPeriodDate(),
            this.flightsService.getTagOns(),
            this.flightsService.getTagOnTargetRecipients(),
            this.flightsService.getInventories()
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(
        ([user, campaign, date, tagOns, tagOnTargetRecipients, allInventories]) => {
          this.isLoading = false;

          if (user.account) {
            this.account = user.account;
            this.inventories = this.account.inventories;

            if (this.account.features) {
              this.hasProfileFeature = this.account.features.some(
                feature => feature.code === FeatureCode.PROFILES
              );

              this.hasLocationFeature = this.account.features.some(
                feature => feature.code === FeatureCode.LOCATIONS
              );

              this.hasRecipientGatheringFeature = this.account.features.some(
                feature => feature.code === FeatureCode.RECIPIENT_GATHERING
              );

              this.hasParameterisedContactListFeature = this.account.features.some(
                feature =>
                  feature.code === FeatureCode.PARAMETERISED_CONTACT_LIST
              );

              this.hasInteractiveSMSFeature = this.account.features.some(
                feature =>
                  feature.code === FeatureCode.INTERACTIVE_SMS
              );

              this.addInteractiveSMS(this.hasInteractiveSMSFeature, allInventories, this.inventories )
            }

            if (this.account.addressProfile) {
              this.addressProfile = this.account.addressProfile;
            }
          }

          this.tagOns = tagOns;
          this.tagOnTargetRecipients = tagOnTargetRecipients;
          this.campaign = campaign;
          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.campaign));
          this.approvalPeriodStartDate = date;
        },
        () => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      );
  }



  handleSave({
    currentValue,
    stepIndex
  }: {
    currentValue: Partial<Flight>;
    stepIndex: number;
  }) {
    const request: Partial<Flight> = {
      ...currentValue,
      campaign: this.campaign
    };
    const titleKey = 'HEADINGS.FLIGHT_CREATED';
    let bodyKey = '';

    this.isSaving = true;

    this.flightsService
      .create(request)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(flight => {
          this.router.navigate(['/flights', flight.id, 'edit'], {
            queryParams: { startStepIndex: stepIndex }
          });

          request.impressionLimit !== flight.impressionLimit
            ? (bodyKey = 'MESSAGES.IMPRESSIONS_CHANGED')
            : (bodyKey = 'MESSAGES.FLIGHT_SAVED_DRAFT');

          return request.impressionLimit !== flight.impressionLimit
            ? this.translateService.get([titleKey, bodyKey], {
                name: request.name,
                impressions: flight.impressionLimit
              })
            : this.translateService.get([titleKey, bodyKey], {
                name: request.name
              });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        translations => {
          this.isSaving = false;

          this.toastService.toast({
            type: 'success',
            title: translations[titleKey],
            body: translations[bodyKey],
            icon: 'paper-plane',
            timeout: 10000
          });
        },
        () => {
          this.isSaving = false;
        }
      );
  }

  saveAsDraft(currentValue: Partial<Flight>) {
    const titleKey = 'HEADINGS.FLIGHT_CREATED';
    const bodyKey = 'MESSAGES.FLIGHT_SAVED_DRAFT';

    const request: Partial<Flight> = {
      ...currentValue,
      campaign: this.campaign,
      parameterisedContactList: this.parameterisedContactList,
      status: {
        code: FlightStatusCode.DRAFT
      }
    };

    this.isSaving = true;
    this.flightsService
      .create(request)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(flight => {
          this.router.navigate(['/flights', flight.id, 'edit'], {
            queryParams: { startStepIndex: 1 }
          });

          return this.translateService.get([titleKey, bodyKey], {
            name: request.name
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        translations => {
          this.isSaving = false;
          this.toastService.toast({
            type: 'success',
            title: translations[titleKey],
            body: translations[bodyKey],
            icon: 'paper-plane',
            timeout: 10000
          });
        },
        () => {
          this.isSaving = false;
        }
      );
  }

}
```

the error is happening at this.route.paramMap in the ngOnit method. not sure what is wrong here . appreciate if you can help , thank you